# Proxy settings for Kafka Mirror maker

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am relatively new to apache KAFKA :(

use case:
1) My company has a Data center on Azure and the Service provider is on AWS.
2) Need to mirror the topics from the kafka cluster from one data center to the other data center.
3) looking at Mirror maker for the above use case.

Issues:
1) Network connection between these data centers are through firewall proxies.
2) I dont see any documentation for using proxies in Mirror maker connection settings in either consumer or producer.

Question:
1) Does kafka support proxies in their connection connection settings?
2) if yes can you please provide the details on this settings?

thanks

Comment: What I am looking is how to configure a proxy settings to consume a topic from DC-1 kafka cluster by a Consumer running in in DC-2. (DC - Data center). The network connection between these two DC's are through firewall proxies and I dont see a settings in KAFKA to specify this proxy details. Does that help? or what specifics are you looking for? thanks

Comment: Is advertised.listeners property of the broker configuration used for this proxy host:port settings?